# "a" tags getting duplicating and applied to nearby text -- why?

Tags: html, css, confluence

I have a page with the following html:

```
<a name="CAPTION_fig1" rel="nofollow" /><p style="margin-top: -0.2em; font-size: 85%; margin-bottom: 0.9em;"><b>Figure 1: This a caption</b></p>
```

which essentially boils down to:

```
<anchor><p>Text</p>
```

But it doesn't look right when I open the page, so I examine it using Inspect Element in Chrome. It reports:

```
<a name="CAPTION_fig1" rel="nofollow"></a>
<a name="CAPTION_fig1" rel="nofollow"><p style="margin-top: -0.2em; font-size: 85%; margin-bottom: 0.9em;"><b>Figure 1: This a caption</b></p></a>
```

Why on earth is this happening? When I do view source, it still looks as I expect it to. I've also tried IE9, so it doesn't seem to be browser-specific.

Some background: I am in the process of upgrading Confluence, so I suspect that it is related to some new CSS being used, but I have no idea what or why.

BTW, I found a similar issue here: [Anchor tags are duplicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187983/anchor-tags-are-duplicating), but his website and the attached picture are gone, plus the answer only includes the final css, and not what he changed, so it doesn't give me much to go on.

Comment: Have you tried separating the closing `<a>` (Like `<a name=... nofollow"></a>`)?

Comment: I have, but it was inconclusive. They seemed to combine again in generated source code. I'm not sure if it is Confluence or Chrome that is messing with my html.

Comment: `<a>` isn't a self-closing tag, you need to specify the `</a>` closing tag.  It's likely the browser is trying to make a best guess about what should be in the tag.

Comment: But duplicating the a tag seems like a pretty poor job of a best guess.

Comment: Hm, I put a space between the <a> and </a> and then Confluence/Chrome seemed to behave better. It must be Confluence's new xhtml handler that messes with things in a way that confuses Chrome. Looks like the problem is solved for now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the precise causes of this error, but if anyone else has these problems when developing for Confluence, then separating the  and  tags (not using a self closing tag) and putting a space between them seems to help.

I'm going to venture that is caused by Confluence combining the  tags into one self-closing tag (either to ensure xhtml compliance or because of an error) but that Chrome and IE9 couldn't parse this because it isn't html4 compliant (according to jmoerdyk, a tags cannot be self-closing).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this problem has been resolved, but I just want to mention a similar issue I had. For a while, I was converting old html pages to wikimarkup on confluence but every time I would saved the editor it would add a lot of unwanted line-breaks.

The problem was apparently caused by copying content to the rich-text editor and then switching to the wiki-markup editor.